# Проблемы с авторизацией через ВК(сбрасывает)

Tags: android, вконтакте, авторизация

Всем привет! Нужна помощь или совет в какую сторону капать.

Реализую авторизацию в приложении через ВК. После успешной авторизации, если не пользоваться приложением некоторое время (в среднем на android 8.0 около 6-8 часов, на android 7.0 12 часов), то происходит разлогинивание.

При проверке на входе метод `VK.isLoggedIn()` вернет `false`. Пробовал запрашивать бессрочный токен `(List<VKScope> tmp=new ArrayList<>(); tmp.add(VKScope.OFFLINE);VK.login(LoginActivity.this,tmp);)`, но ситуация не изменилась.

Comment: Задам вопрос пальцем в небо, т.к. не работал с авторизацией ВК, но все же: а сохраняете полученный токен? =) В смысле может вы проводите авторизацию, потом сворачиваете приложение, и когда система его окончательно убивает вы теряете состояние вместе с токеном. И тогда не важно сколько он действует со стороны сервера, если у вас его нет

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий SDK BK сама сохраняет токен, можно выгрузить приложение или перезагрузить телефон и зайти без проблем.